# Union::normal: Nonatomic expression expected when using Uncompress

Tags: warning-messages, compression

I saved a expresion to a file like this

```
Export["file.dat",Compress@myExpression];
```

Then (i don't know why) when I import the file i get the compressed expresion embedded in a nested list like this:

```
test = Import["file.dat"] (* test -> {{ compressedString }} *)
```

So I use this to Uncompress the expresion:

```
myExp = Uncompress@First@Flatten@Import["file.dat"];
```

And I get my expresion back correctly, but i get these msg

```
Union::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 2 in <<1>>. >>
Union::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 2 in <<1>>. >>
```

Should I worry about those msg? Why am I getting those?

You can check for yourselves: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35192406/bad.dat

Comment: The .dat file is assumed to contain tabular data, so `Import` gives you a 2D list. You can use `Import["file.dat", "Text"]` to get the string directly. The messages are presumably coming from the evaluation of `myExpression`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a undefined variable `games` in the compressed data. The code in the compressed data attempts to do a union on this `games` variable and some lists. So essentially, the error you get is the same one caused by

```
Union[{}, games]
```

To see it for yourself, try using `Uncompress` with two arguments. I suggest to use `HoldComplete` as a second argument.

We then have

```
MatchQ[heldData, HoldComplete[Union[___]]]
```

> True